# How can I create a Kotlin class that can be used in a for loop?

Tags: kotlin

I have a custom implementation of a list which returns a new item if none is contained within it.

```kt
@Parcelize
class ListOfItems(private val list: Map<String, Item> = mapOf()) : Parcelable {
    operator fun get(name: String) = list[name] ?: Item(name)
}
```

I'd like to use it inside `for` loop:

```kt
val myListOfItems = ListOfItems(/* ... */)
for (item in myListOfItems)
{
    // Do something...
}
```

How can I achieve it? Is there some interface that I have to implement o some method that I have to add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Jordi noticed, you need to implement `Iterable` interface. This could be done even simplier:

```kotlin
class ListOfItems(private val list: Map<String, Item> = mapOf()) : Parcelable, Iterable<Item> by list.values {
    operator fun get(name: String) = list[name] ?: Item(name)
}
```

Moreover, you may implement not `Iterable` but `Collection` interface (which extends `Iterable`) in the same way, taking advantage of various [extension members](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-collection/#extension-properties) defined for `Collection`:

```kotlin
class ListOfItems(private val list: Map<String, Item> = mapOf()) : Parcelable, Collection<Item> by list.values {
    operator fun get(name: String) = list[name] ?: Item(name)
}
```

Or even `List` (to make class name consistent with its interface):

```kotlin
class ListOfItems(private val list: Map<String, Item> = mapOf()) : Parcelable, List<Item> by list.values.toList() {
    operator fun get(name: String) = list[name] ?: Item(name)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin, for a class to be used in a `for` loop it must implement `Iterable<T>` interface.

As per your example:

```kt
@Parcelize
class ListOfItems(private val list: Map<String, Item> = mapOf()) : Parcelable, Iterable<Item> {
    operator fun get(name: String) = list[name] ?: Item(name)

    override fun iterator(): Iterator<Item> = list.values.iterator()
}
```